# Flow Decision Condition is failing

Tags: visual-workflow, conditional

I have a custom Object `Request__c`

These are the fields on the `Request__c` record

- `Account_Executive__c`   (lookup to Contact record)
- `Central_Services__c`      (lookup to Contact record)
- `Opportunity__c`       (lookup to Opportunity)
- `Status__c`            (Picklist with values  'A' , 'B' , 'Completed')

**Use Case**

When the Opportunity Status  is updated to 'Completed'  AND the Opportunity_Lookup isNull
Send an email alert to the Account_Executive, and to the Central_Service__c contacts

**This is my flow**

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

**These are two Test Cases and Test outcome**

**Test Case 1 = Pass**

Opportunity = opp1
Update Status__c =  'Completed'
Account_Executive__c =  'ContactAE' // has email
Central_Services__c =  null

**Test Case 2 = Fail**

Opportunity = opp2
Update Status__c =  'Completed'
Account_Executive__c =  null
Central_Services__c =  'Central Services AE' // has email

Why is my 2nd Test Case failing ?  What's wrong with the Condition ?

(1 AND 2)  OR (3 AND 4)   --> is this not logically correct ?

Email Alert is received for 1st Test Case
Email Alert not received for 2nd Test Case

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem.

In the Email Alert I had not selected the Email recipient to be 'Central Services'